# Why pygame.midi doesn't work on macos whereas pygame.mixer does

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame, midi

I want to write a piece of software in Python3x, which will play Midi notes. I have this example code here on Stack Overflow :

```
import pygame.midi
import time

pygame.midi.init()
player = pygame.midi.Output(0)
player.set_instrument(0)
player.note_on(64, 127)
time.sleep(1)
player.note_off(64, 127)
del player
pygame.midi.quit()
```

It works perfectly fine on Windows, but not on Mac, where I get this error:

```
pygame.midi.MidiException: 'Device id invalid, out of range.'
```

I understand that there is no Midi device enabled. 
But when I play some regular midi file using mixer:

```
...
pygame.mixer.music.load('whatever.mid')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
...
```

it plays correctly, which puzzles me. Other applications using Midi, like Musescore, work perfectly well also.

My questions are:

1. Why does mixer work, and pygame.midi doesn't?
2. How can I fix it so that pygame.midi would produce a sound?

(It occured to me that I could generate midi file with my app and then put it into the mixer, but it's clumsy and there must be a better way)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT1:
I have tried to enable IAC and add a bus.
When I try to get device info:

```
for n in range(pygame.midi.get_count()):
    print (n,pygame.midi.get_device_info(n))
```

two more devices appear:

```
0 (b'CoreMIDI', b'IAC Driver IAC Bus 1', 1, 0, 0)
1 (b'CoreMIDI', b'IAC Driver IAC Bus 1', 0, 1, 0)
```

Original example fails on fifth line, because 0 is input bus. If changed to 1, it ends without error, but no sound is played (heard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have any MIDI device. So first you need to go to: `MIDI audio configuration`, try to search it on spotlight on your mac, or in `Launchpad>Others>Midi Audio configuration`.
Once you are there, on the top menú, in the `Window>MIDI studio` section, you'll find something called `IAC Driver`, double click on that rectangle and enable the checkbox that says `Connected Device`. Then click on apply and you'll have one virtual MIDI bus.

Comment: Well, now is an instrument problem. IAC only acces MIDI devices. So if you want to hear something you need a Synthethizer software. You can try with Reason. Create a new project and simply add a NNXT synth to the mixer. Then on the Midi configuration on the mixer, choose in the Channel 0 the NNXT-in and try your program. Take a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577001/pygame-midi-midiexception-device-id-invalid-out-of-range

Comment: I don't have Reason, but I have downloaded SimpleSynth after some googling and it works :)
However, it seems to me then, that pygame.mixer uses some builtin synthetiser. Is there a way to connect pygame.midi to it? I would love my app to require as few external dependencies as possible.

Comment: I read something and maybe could help you: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=116715